# How to create a class with a package private constructor?

Tags: java, oop, constructor

I'm working on a library where I want to return an object representing a real world object. I want to expose this class to developers to manipulate the real world object, but I don't want to allow them to construct these objects themselves.

**Example**

```
public class World {
    public static List<RealObject> getAllObjects() {
        // How to create RealObject with physicalID?
    }
}

public class RealObject {
    private int physicalID;

    public RealObject(int physicalID) {
        // Undesirable, user has no knowledge of IDs
    }

    public void setState(int state) {
        // Code using physicalID to change state
    }
}
```

These objects currently have no constructor and have a private `id` field that I set with reflection from within my library. This works perfectly, but I can't help but think there must be a better solution. Perhaps a useful constraint in my situation is that it only needs to be possible to construct this object from one other class.

Is there a better solution? And is it still possible to have the class in a separate file in that case for organizational purposes?

Comment: Please add some example code.

Comment: use factory pattern http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern

Comment: @user902383 How does that solve the problem? It'll still be a factory method public to the users.

Comment: @Overv sorry i missunderstand you, you want to create your objects, and give them to use, but you want to prevent users to create object given type? sounds for me like enums

Comment: Singleton design pattern?

Comment: @user902383 See example for the type of situation (where singletons and enums are not appropriate).

Comment: @Overv did you consider making your class inner class with public constructor, so can be instantiated in outer class?

Comment: @user902383 That would indeed work, but I think it would clutter the class, because there are other types of objects that are private in the same way.

Comment: Singleton is doing exactly what you want if *you* instanciate the class *first*. The other developpers won't be able to instanciate it again and they'll have a direct access to the class instance.

Comment: @Overv hmmm.. there is other thing, constructor of each class can have default access level, so can be accessed by classes in same package

Comment: @Pol0nium I don't understand how a singleton is a solution when there could be dozens of these objects with different IDs?

Comment: @user902383 Thanks, that works perfectly! Add it as answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @Overv Oh! Sorry, I misread... I thought that your world was unique.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you put default access level on constructor (or any other method), then can be accessed only by classes from same package.

To concretely answer the question in the title:

```
public class RealObject {
  RealObject(int physicalID) {
    // Package-private constructor
  }
}
```